# Using DES s-boxes, and with aid of Figure 1, show that S5 (18) = d, S6 (09) = 7, S7 (12) = c and S8(3d) = 6

Tags: security

Using DES s-boxes, and with aid of Figure 1, show that S5 (18) = d, S6  (09) = 7, S7 (12) = c and S8(3d) = 6.
Can someone please help to answer this question? I just don't understand it

Comment: The figure is actually a DES S-Box. You can find it online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**S5 (18) = d**

```
18 (hex) = 00011000 (Binary)

outer=00        row 0

inner=1100      col 12

S5 row 0    col 12 = 13

13 in hex = d
```

---

**S6 (09) = 7**

```
09 (hex) = 00001001 (Binary)

outer=  01      row 1

inner= 0100column 4

s6 row 1    column 4 =7
7 in hex = 7
```

---

**S7 (12) = c**

```
12 (hex) =  010010 (Binary)

outer = 00      row 0
inner = 1001    Column 9

S7 row 0        column 9 = 12

12 in hex = c
```

---

**S8 (3d) = 6**

```
3d= 00111101

outer = 11      row 3
inner = 1110    column 14

S8 row 3    column 14 = 6
6 in hex =6
```